# Change of summation order in $\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i}^n a_{j-i}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I have to show that $$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i}^n a_{j-i}$$ is equal to $$\sum_{j=0}^n (n+1-j)a_{j}$$
I can change order of summation or add i to internal sum:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i}^n a_{j-i} = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^j a_{j-i} = \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} a_{j}$$
But I don't know if it leads somewhere?

Or if I will rewrite this as:
$$a_{0} + a_{1} + ... + a_{n}$$
$$+ a_{0} + a_{1} + ... + a_{n-1}$$
$$...$$
$$+ a_{0} + a_{1}$$
$$+ a_{0}$$

And if we'll add columns instead of rows, then sum is $na_{0} + (n-1)a_{1} ... $ etc. But this takes time and I'm looking for faster way, maybe just operating on sigma simbol can lead to this result?

Answer (score 2):

Add $i$ to the internal sum AND change the order of summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{n-i} a_j = \sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^{n-j} a_j = \sum_{j=0}^n (n+1-j)a_j$$

Comment: can you explain why internal sum is from 0 to n-j?

Comment: because bounds for our summation region are characterized by the lines $i=0$, $j=0$, and $i+j=n$

Comment: @abc2343 read my comment

Answer (score 2):

The sum is just $\sum n_j a_j$ where $n_j$ is the number of ways of writing $j$ as $l-m$ with $l \geq m$. [All variable between $0$ and $n$]. There are $n+1-j$ ways of choosing $l \geq j$ and for each such $l$ we have the unique value $m=l-j$.